# Does this decomposition theorem of stationary process exist?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity

I have this vague impression that there was a theorem on Wikipedia about stationary process, saying that if $(x_k)$ is a strictly stationary process, then there exists a decomposition in the form of $x_k = \displaystyle\sum_{i=-\infty}^0 \rho_{i}\xi_{k+i}$, such that $\xi_i$ and $\xi_j$ are uncorrelated.

In my case, $x_k$ and $\xi_i$ are all supposed to be Gaussian.

Now I can not find this theorem on Wikipedia, or anywhere online. Does anyone know whether this theorem exist? And what is the exact statement of this theorem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I understand what you seek for, but there is nothing preventing me to use $\rho_0=1,\rho_i=0\ \forall i <0$, and $\xi_{k+i}=x_k$ to satisfy the equation. I think there must be more constraints.

Comment: @gunes Yes $\xi$'s are uncorrelated.

Comment: [Wold's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @corey979 Yes. That must be the theorem I saw. Thanks.